# data entry not happening in php through form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

Data insertion is not happening when user is entering through a form.i am trying to ask user for firstname , lastname and phone number through 3 fields checking pattern side by side but data is not being inserted in db.
The code is as ->

main page i.e. allinfo.php:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php 
    $labels=array("firstname"=>"FirstName" , "lastname"=>"LastName" ,"phone"=>"PhoneNumber");
    ?>
    <form action='blank.php' method='POST'>
        <?php
    foreach ($labels as $field => $value) 
    {
        echo "<label for='$field'>$value</label>";
        echo "<input type='text'  name='$field'>";
    }
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>";

       ?>
    </form>
</body>
```

Other page:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php 
    /*foreach($_POST as $field=>$value)
    {
        echo "$field = $value<br />";
    }*/
    /*foreach($_POST as $field)
    {
        echo "$field <br />";
    }*/
    $labels=array("firstname"=>"FirstName" , "lastname"=>"LastName" ,"phone"=>"PhoneNumber");
    foreach ($_POST as $field => $name) 
    {
        if($field!='lastname')
        {
            if(empty($name))
            {
                $blank_array[]=$field;
            }
        }   
            elseif($field=="phone")
            {
                if(!preg_match("/^ [0-9 ) ( -] {7-20} $/" , $name))
                {
                    $bad_array[]=$field;
                }

            }
    }
    if(@sizeof($blank_array) > 0 or @sizeof($bad_array) > 0)
{
    if(@sizeof($blank_array) > 0)
    {
        echo "<p>You have missed some of the values</p>";
        foreach($blank_array as $name)
        {
            echo "{$labels[$name]}<br />";
        }
    }
    if(@sizeof($bad_array) > 0) 
    {

        echo "Please enter in correct format";
        foreach($bad_array as $name)
        {
            echo "{$labels[$name]}";
        }
    }
        echo "<form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]' method='POST'>";                   /* re-display the form*/
        foreach($labels as $field=>$name)
        {
            $good_data[$field]=strip_tags(trim($_POST[$field]));
            echo "<label for='$field'>$name</label>";
            echo "<input type='text'  name='$field' value='{$good_data[$field]}'>";
        }
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>";
        echo "</form>";
}

else
{
    $host="localhost";
    $acc="root";
    $password="*******";
    $database="member";
    $cxn=mysqli_connect($host,$acc,$password,$database) or die("can not found");
    foreach($labels as $field=> $name)
    {
        $good_data[$field]=strip_tags(trim($_POST[$field]));
        if($field=="phone")
        {
            $good_data[$field]=preg_replace("/ [) ( . -] / " , " " , $good_data[$field]);
        }   
            $good_data[$field]=mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn,$good_data[$field]);
    }
        $query="insert into user (";
            foreach($good_data as $field =>$name)
            {
                $query.="$field";
            }
        $query.=") VALUES (";
        $query=preg_replace("/,\)/",")",$query) ;
        foreach($good_data as $field =>$name)
            {
                $query.="'$name',";
            }
            $query.=")";
            $query=preg_replace("/,\)/",")",$query) ;
            $result=mysqli_query($cxn,$query);
            echo "new entry";

}
    echo "<p>All the information is available &hearts; </p>"    ;

    ?>
</body>
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you seeing any output at all?

Comment: yes but not desired as: new entry

All the information is available ♥

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop where you build the query string

```
foreach($good_data as $field =>$name)
        {
            $query.="$field";
}
```

To

```
foreach($good_data as $field =>$name)
        {
            $query.="$field,";
}
```

Notice you missed the coma.

Comment: I have only validated last name and phone. You can all other fields like this.

Comment: hi Bansi,
Thank you for your suggestion but the status is still same. it is showing as:
new entry
All the information is available
but still no entry in table "user" in database "member"

Comment: I got the result on my own but still thank you all for your valuable suggestions and solutions.

Comment: Bansi :Still it is not working with above code you have editted.